# Bash: awk usage and placement into array with 3 conditions

Tags: bash, awk

For the last few months I've been dependent on using this line of code to grab what I need from a file:

```
declare -a arr_dbs=(`awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora-11' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab`)
```

This runs through the /etc/oratab file, that has some text like such:

```
# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
OEM:/software/oracle/agent/agent12c/core/12.1.0.3.0:N
*:/software/oracle/agent/agent11g:N
#dev360:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.02:Y
#dev364:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.02:N
dev661:/software/oracle/ora-10.02.00.04.11:Y
dev663:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.11:Y
dev360:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev361:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:Y
dev362:/software/oracle/ora-11.02.00.04.02:N
```

Simply put, I am looking to grab the items `dev663, dev360, dev361`. This is because they:

1. Are not commented out (line starts with `#`)
2. Contain `/software/oracle/ora-11` meaning an Oracle 11 database (I suppose this could be shortened to `/ora-11`)
3. Have an `:Y` at the end of the line. As the documentation states, that means it's active.

I am hitting a roadblock because of these conditions. Previously (the code above) was grabbing all the items. I fixed up a few things so I thought it would take care of the :N but it looks like I did that incorrectly:

```
# Collect the databases using a mixture of AWK and regex, and throw it into an array.
declare -a arr_dbs=(`awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora-11' '$2 ~ key{print $1}' /etc/oratab`)

# After initializing our iterator to zero, the loop goes through the array and looks for
# entries that should not be there.
db_counter=0
for i in "${arr_dbs[@]}"
do
    # Grab the last character via AWK. If it's "N" or "n", remove it from the array
    # "N" represents the database no longer being on that server or being active.
    #last_char=`echo $i | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'`
    last_char=`echo $i | tail -c 1`
    if [ "$last_char" == "N" ] || [ "$last_char" == "n" ]; then
        #echo $i
        unset arr_dbs[$db_counter]
    fi
    ((db_counter++))
done
```

Any assistance writing code meeting those three conditions would be greatly appreciated. The end goal is to have a neat array that contains, according to the above example,

```
dev663
dev360 
dev361
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text. The tool to manipulate text is awk and you're already using it so just tweak that to do what you want instead of trying to force shell to do something it was never designed to do:

```
$ awk -F: -v key='/software/oracle/ora-11' '{sub(/#.*/,"")} ($2~key) && ($3~/Y/){print $1}' file
dev663
dev360
dev361
```

The sub() removes all commented-out text (no matter where it starts on each line) and then you just test the 2 conditions you care about. I'm using a regexp comparison for Y instead of a string equality comparison in case you have any trailing white space.

Comment: I definitely can't compete with yours, a `++` but does mine make sense somehow?

Comment: Yes, it'd work too as long as `ora-11` can't appear anywhere other than in the 2nd field but you might want to add a `[[:space:]]*` between `Y` and `$` and change `<blank>` to `[[:space:]]` between `^` and `*`. I'm also assuming the OP needs to use a variable `key` too for some reason but maybe not, idk.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Ed!

Answer (score 3):

An `awk` like below, updated as per [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) comments.

```
awk -F":" '!/^[[:blank:]]*#/ && /ora-11/ && /:Y[[:space:]]*$/{print $1}' file
dev663
dev360
dev361
```

I have combined multiple regular expressions into one which stand for

- Not starting with `#` (and)
- Having a pattern `ora-11` (and)
- Havin g a pattern `:Y` at the end

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk -F: '!/^#/ && /ora-11/ && /Y$/ {print $1}' file

dev663
dev360
dev361
```

Answer (score 2):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -rn '/ora-11/{s/^([^#].*):.*:Y$/\1/p}' file

dev663
dev360
dev361
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F: -v key="/software/oracle/ora-11" '$0 ~ "[^#]" key && /Y$/ && $0=$1' file
dev663
dev360
dev361
```